# Appium AndroidElement EditText disallow change

Tags: java, android, appium

I have an android application with two EditText elements. The app works as the following: when value is changed in one of them, the value in the other changes as well. I would like EditText value not to change when I change it in the other one.

I have tried to look for an "editable" or "enabled" property to set it false, but can access to it. The instance of the EditText elements is AndroidElement.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you elaborate more? and use different names like `EditText1` and `EditText2` please, its hard to understand the issue

Comment: I don't have the code of the app, so I'll try to explain better:
Start situation:
EditText1 value: ""(blank)
EditText2 value: "foo"
The behaviour of the app is that every time we type something on EditText1 (e.g. bar), the value of EditText2 changes (e.g. foo bar).
I just wondered if I can use something like EditText2.setEnabled(false) in order to disallow EditText2 to change value.
I'm getting the EditText elements with:
MobileElement eT = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(
                    By.xpath("//[...]/android.widget.EditText[@resource-id='com.example.example/resourceId']")